# Validar Solo Texto y punto JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validación, script

Estoy usando el Framework **Fancygrid.com**, y necesito validar en un Field para que acepte solo textos y punto, me explico. Tengo un campo llamado usuario y la estructura es: **juan.cruz** Como pueden observar la validación del Field debe aceptar letras y el signo (.) y tambien solo debe escribirse en minusculas.

Yo tengo un ejemplo de como crear una función en fancygrid y aplicarlo al Field.

```
<script>
//Esta es mi función de ejemplo
var formatNumberInput = function(value){
   if(/\.$/.test(value)){
      return value;
   }

   if(/\./.test(value)){
      var splitted = value.split('.');

      if(splitted[1].length > 2){
         splitted[1] = splitted[1].substring(0, 2);
      }
      value = splitted[0] + '.' + splitted[1];
   }

   value = parseFloat(value);

   if(isNaN(value)){
      value = '';
   }

   return value;
}

//Aqui se aplica al Field
items: [{
  type: 'number',
  width:72,
  labelAlign: 'top',
  label: 'Cap(*)',
  emptyText: 'Cap',
  name: 'n_capacidad',
  checkValidOnTyping: true,
  format: { inputFn: formatNumberInput }
}],

</script>
```

Les paso este ejemplo para que vean como es la estructura que acepta Fancygrid, yo soy nuevo recién en usar frameworks y sobretodo en javascript, es por eso que necesito que me den una mano para crear la **función de texto con punto y solo minúsculas**.
Gracias

Comment: El texto puede incluir números, o solo letras y la forma es nombre1.nombre2??

Comment: El campo debe aceptar solo texto y el punto, y solo debe permitir minúsculas. El campo se llama usuario, y la estructura es suprimernombre.suprimerapellido. Gracias por tu apoyo

Answer (score 2):

```
var formatNumberInput = function(value){
   return /^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$/.test(value);
}
```

Con esto solo devolveria true si el valor de la variable value es texto en minúscula seguido de un punto y otro texto en minúscula creo que era esto lo que buscabas, ejemplo pablo.alberto

Comment: Aplique la función pero cuando digito en mi campo me sale false.

Comment: A ver a que te refieres con digito?? y que te sale false??

Comment: Yo estoy tratando de validar un campo en mi formulario. Yo he aplicado  la función que has creado y cuando escribo en mi campo o textbox automáticamente me sale false.

Comment: Aunque termines de escribirlo todo y tenga este valor  **juan.cruz**

Comment: Es que no escribe nada defrente me sale false en el textbox

Comment: Entonces tienes que revisar bien que es lo que debes pasarle a format.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar una expresion regex.

Seria algo asi:

```
function check(texto){

//Cualquier caracter de a-z, punto o espacio
let re = /[a-z]|\.|\s/;

if (re.test(texto)){
//Sigue la estructura
} else {
//invalido
}
}
```

Si quieres investigar más sobre regex mira esto [Introducción regex mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)